# How to reload schema.rb in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a few migrations which were created when I initially created models using rails generate model. I've run those migrations and successfully updated the database.

I've then made some changes to these migrations (not added new ones) because they were very small changes like a new column, or making a column unique, or adding an index.

But, even when I reset my db and run all migrations again, rails is insisting on using an outdated schema.rb file.

What should I be doing? How do I force a reload of this schema.rb?

Comment: Remember next time that you should not change a migration after you did `db:migrate`. It's even worst if you are developing in a team, where everyone can change the schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you haven't pushed the code to production you can run `rake db:rollback` then `rake db:migrate` to drop and recreate the tables.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```